# Exporting function(s) does not make it available in other module

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

I'm trying to use the retrieve_endpoints function in cli_config.js.
I added the functions to the module exports and added the require in the cli_config file.
Why can't I seem to call the retrieve_endpoints function?

**collector.js**

```
async function retrieve_endpoints(enviromnent) {
    let configured_endpoints = []; 

    return configured_endpoints;
}



module.exports = ({ server }) => {
    return {
        retrieve_endpoints
    };
}
```

**cli_config.js**

```
const collector = require('../collector/collector');



function webapi_source({ menus }) {
    endpoints = await collector.retrieve_endpoints(env);
            
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem with your example is that you replace the `exports` object with a function that returns an object in `collector.js`, but in `cli_config.js` you don't call that function, you expect a bare object. Based on your example I think you don't need that function in the first place. Sulman is also right that there is a syntax error around `async / await`, and a few others, but I think those problems are probably just a copy-paste error.

## Using ECMA modules

It's 2024, I suggest you rather to write [Standard ECMAScript Modules](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html). All you have to do is to rename your files to `.mjs`, this will allow you to use the `export / import` syntax.

**collector.mjs**

```
export async function retrieve_endpoints(enviromnent) {
    let configured_endpoints = []; 

    return configured_endpoints;
}
```

**cli_config.mjs**

```
import { retrieve_endpoints } from '../collector/collector.mjs';

async function webapi_source({ menus }) {
    endpoints = await retrieve_endpoints(env);
}
```

## Using CommonJS

If you *have* to use [CommonJS Modules](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html), then the fix would look something like this:

**collector.js**

```
async function retrieve_endpoints(enviromnent) {
    let configured_endpoints = []; 

    return configured_endpoints;
}

module.exports.retrieve_endpoints = retrieve_endpoints;
```

**cli_config.js**

```
const collector = require('../collector/collector');

async function webapi_source({ menus }) {
    endpoints = await collector.retrieve_endpoints(env);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue in your webapi_source function is that you are trying to use the await keyword without marking the function as async.

```
async function webapi_source({ menus }) {
    endpoints = await collector.retrieve_endpoints(env);
}
```